# Creating datamart with spagobimeta

Tags: olap, cube, spagobi, datamart

I am trying to make an olap cube with Spago BI.

After creating the tables of dimensions and the table of fact in SpagoBI Meta, I launched the execution for getting the datamart.

Unfortunately I got this error :

[image]

What should I do to resolve this?

[image]